# How do I use the Load function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For saving I created structures in the state class :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class SaveState
{
    public struct Position
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;

        public void Fill(Vector3 v3)
        {
            x = v3.x;
            y = v3.y;
            z = v3.z;
        }

        public Vector3 V3 { get { return new Vector3(x, y, z); } set { Fill(value); } }
    }

    public struct Rotation
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
        public float w;

        public void Fill(Quaternion Quat)
        {
            x = Quat.x;
            y = Quat.y;
            z = Quat.z;
            w = Quat.w;
        }

        public Quaternion Qua { get { return new Quaternion(x, y, z, w); } set { Fill(value); } }
    }

    public struct Scale
    {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float z;
        public float w;

        public void Fill(Vector3 v3)
        {
            x = v3.x;
            y = v3.y;
            z = v3.z;
        }

        public Vector3 V3 { get { return new Vector3(x, y, z); } set { Fill(value); } }
    }

    public SaveState(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot, Vector3 sca)
    {
        Position position = new Position();
        position.V3 = pos;

        Rotation qua = new Rotation();
        qua.Qua = rot;

        Scale scale = new Scale();
        scale.V3 = sca;
    }
}
```

Then in the manager script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class SaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void Save(SaveState player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.bin";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, player);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static SaveState Load()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.bin";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            SaveState data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as SaveState;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

And test script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            var player = GameObject.Find("Player");
            SaveState saveState = new SaveState(player.transform.position, player.transform.rotation,player.transform.localScale);

            SaveManager.Save(saveState);
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {
            var player = GameObject.Find("Player");


        }
    }
}
```

The save part seems to be ok but the load part I'm not sure.
I'm not sure if the Load function is written good and not sure how to use it in the L key input.

Edit :

My classes and scripts after updates :

Save State :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

[Serializable]
public class SaveState
{
    public struct SerializableVector3
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;

        public SerializableVector3(Vector3 v)
        {
            X = v.x;
            Y = v.y;
            Z = v.z;
        }

        // And now some magic
        public static implicit operator SerializableVector3(Vector3 v)
        {
            return new SerializableVector3(v);
        }

        public static implicit operator Vector3(SerializableVector3 sv)
        {
            return new Vector3(sv.X, sv.Y, sv.Z);
        }
    }

    public struct SerializableQuaternion
    {
        public float X;
        public float Y;
        public float Z;
        public float W;

        public SerializableQuaternion(Quaternion q)
        {
            X = q.x;
            Y = q.y;
            Z = q.z;
            W = q.w;
        }

        public static implicit operator SerializableQuaternion(Quaternion q)
        {
            return new SerializableQuaternion(q);
        }

        public static implicit operator Quaternion(SerializableQuaternion sq)
        {
            return new Quaternion(sq.X, sq.Y, sq.Z, sq.W);
        }
    }

    public SerializableVector3 position;
    public SerializableQuaternion rotation;
    public SerializableVector3 scale;

    public SaveState(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot, Vector3 sca)
    {
        position = pos;
        rotation = rot;
        scale = sca;
    }

    public void ApplyToPlayer(Transform player)
    {
        player.position = position;
        player.rotation = rotation;
        player.localScale = scale;
    }
}
```

Manager :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class SaveManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static void Save(SaveState player)
    {
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.bin";
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create);

        formatter.Serialize(stream, player);
        stream.Close();
    }

    public static SaveState Load()
    {
        string path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/player.bin";
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);

            SaveState data = formatter.Deserialize(stream) as SaveState;
            stream.Close();

            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogError("Save file not found in " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Test script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.T))
        {
            var player = GameObject.Find("Player");
            SaveState saveState = new SaveState(player.transform.position, player.transform.rotation, player.transform.localScale);
            SaveManager.Save(saveState);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {
            var player = GameObject.Find("Player");

            var playerInfo = SaveManager.Load();
            playerInfo.ApplyToPlayer(player.transform);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You currently don't have any fields in your class!**

Only type definitions. You will need some like

```
public Position position;
public Rotation rotation;
public Scale scale;
```

The ones you used are just local method variables that won't be stored anywhere!

And in the constructor assign these

```
public SaveState(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot, Vector3 sca)
{
    // Since structs are never null
    // you don't need to create new ones
    position.V3 = pos;
    rotation.Qua = rot;
    scale.V3 = sca;
}
```

---

Then I usually go for a method within your class itself like e.g.

```
public void ApplyToPlayer(Transform player)
{
    player.position = position.V3;
    player.rotation = rotation.Qua;
    player.localScale = scale.V3;
}
```

and then in your `L` block

```
var player = GameObject.Find("Player").transform;
var playerInfo = SaveManager.Load();

playerInfo.ApplyToPlayer(player);
```

---

As a last step:

For your structs I would even rather recommend to write `implicit operator` conversions as one example:

```
[Serializable]
public struct SerializableVector3
{
    public float X;
    public float Y;
    public float Z;

    public SerializableVector3(Vector3 v)
    {
        X = v.x;
        Y = v.y;
        Z = v.z;
    }

    // And now some magic
    public static implicit operator SerializableVector3 (Vector3 v)
    {
        return new SerializableVector3 (v);
    }

    public static implicit operator Vector3 (SerializableVector3 sv)
    {
        return new Vector3 (sv.X, sv.Y, sv.Z);
    }
}
```

This allows you now to simply use both types exchangeably like you could rather use

```
public SerializableVector3 position;
// This type is your homework
public SerializableQuaternion rotation;
public SerializableVector3 scale;
```

and then you can directly assign them like

```
player.position = someSaveStat.position;
```

and also

```
someSaveStat.position = player.position;
```

So you could change the constructor to e.g.

```
public SaveState(Vector3 pos, Quaternion rot, Vector3 sca)
{
    position = pos;
    rotation = rot;
    scale = sca;
}
```

and the apply method would become

```
public void ApplyToPlayer (Transform player)
{
    player.position = position;
    player.rotation = rotation;
    player.localScale = scale;
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear.*

Comment: To add the ApplyToPlayer in the SaveState class ? I'm getting errors on Position.V3 and Rotation.Qua and Scale.V3 all same error : An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SaveState.Rotation.Qua'

Comment: Updated. You don't have any fields in your class so nothing will get stored at all...

Comment: SerializableQuaternion is not exist

Comment: @DanielLip .. exactly .. you'll have to implement it using the example I showed you of `SerializeableVector3` extending it with one more field `public float w` and using `Quaternion` as type for the implicit operators .. that's a little homework here ;) Don't want to rob you the chance to do some learning by doing ;) Also as said I'm typing on my phone so ..

Comment: In the T key input for saving I did : var player = GameObject.Find("Player");
            SaveState saveState = new SaveState(player.transform.position, player.transform.rotation,player.transform.localScale);
            SaveManager.Save(saveState); SaveState when init it should get parameters but you mentioned I can do only someSaveStat.position = player.position; But if already in the constructor I give the player parameters why should I do also someSaveStat.position = player.position; ?

Comment: Working great. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`Load()` seems to be OK.

By the way you can also use `FileStream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);`

Nothing really special with using it, just: `SaveState save = SaveManager.Load();`

Comment: So I did inside the input of the L key SaveState save = SaveManager.Load(); but save don't have any propertied. How do I assign the saved values back to the Player transform ?

Comment: When you deserialized your file in `Load()` function, you got SaveState class entity with all your `float` variables for position, rotation, etc. Consider implementing some method to assign all that properties to your player transorm.